# How do I add a boot from cd option to yaboot?

Tags: 12.04, macosx

So I'm dual-booting Ubuntu 12.04.1 on my iMac G5 powepc alongside Mac OS X and I want to add a boot cd option to yaboot because I'm trying to boot a scratched Mac OS X installation DVD that takes a while to read and the frst bootstrap moves on too fast. How do I edit the timeout for the first bootstrap anyways?

So, my main question is, how do I add a cd booting option to yaboot and then, how doI boot it? The devalias from OpenFrmware tells me that 1 have 2 cd-rom instaled, on is /ht/pci@3/ata-6/disk@0 and the other on ends with a 1 instead of a zero.

These are the contents of my yaboot.conf file:

```
yaboot.conf generated by the Ubuntu installer
run: "man yaboot.conf" for details. Do not make changes until you have!!
see also: /usr/share/doc/yaboot/examples for example configurations.
For a dual-boot menu, add one or more of:
bsd=/dev/hdaX, macos=/dev/hdaY, macosx=/dev/hdaZ

boot="/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_ST3160023AS_5MT1GCWA-part2"
device=/ht@0,f2000000/pci@3/k2-sata-root@c/@0/@0
partition=4
root="UUID=798a048f-ee48-49e0-bba3-111aed8dee04"
timeout=12000
install=/usr/lib/yaboot/yaboot
magicboot=/usr/lib/yaboot/ofboot
enablecdboot
macosx="/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_ST3160023AS_5MT1GCWA-part3"

image=/boot/vmlinux
    label=Linux
    read-only
    initrd=/boot/initrd.img
    append="quiet splash"
```

What do I add here so that yaboot will boot from my cd in like 3 minutes after startup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that it was my drive that wasn't reading the DVD and that the "enablecdboot" line in my yaboot configuration file was all I needed in order to boot from a CD. "enableofboot" also gives me an OpenFirmware boot option if I add it to the yaboot.conf!